# linux centos 6.3 hostname (dhcppc4) assigned automatically

Tags: linux, centos

Linux terminal showing hostname dhcppc4 that i never configured. As per configuration files hostname must be localhost :

```
[root@dhcppc4 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain

[root@dhcppc4 ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Note : I attached a new monitor to my laptop.

Don't know how but sometimes terminal shows localhost as hostname.

what is dhcppc4? How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not suitable for stackoverflow (this should be on serverfault i guess)

Anyway, `DHCP` server could even assign an hostname to your machine

Look here: [RFC 1553 - DHCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1533#section-3.14)

Maybe this is your case?

Comment: Thank you Davide .. Is there any way to disable hostname selection from DHCP server?

Comment: If the problem is just what you see on the prompt command, why not edit `PROMPT_COMMAND` env var in `/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: Tomcat server running on my machine is not starting and gnome display not working if i login to root from command prompt in case of new host name.

Answer (score 1):

You are most assuredly allowed to edit the **HOSTNAME** line of that config' file you refer to in your question just fine.

It will not show up until you logout & back in again. You will also want to run **/etc/init.d/rsyslogd restart** (or whatever syslog daemon you are using) to make that name take effect in the log files.

You may or may not need to run a **vi /etc/hosts** to adjust the lines in there as you need for your specific applications. Most will be fine, but some are very very picky, like the otherwise very awesome software, Zimbra, for one example, wont work if those lines are not perfect. Asterisk could be another one that might require that file to be perfect match with your configuration.

You can or can not work with your DHCP server to set this, but most people dont, most edit the HOSTNAME and move on.

It is actually important, though, and do in fact resolve this, dont just leave it, as we sysadmins do not want to be typing mission critical commands at the BASH prompt on the wrong machine when all 6 of your servers all say "localhost".